# sbrk, malloc - max memory that can be allocated

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to figure out how much max memory can be allocated to a process with malloc().

So the gist is :

```
start = sbrk(0);
malloc(1); /* so space is given to the data segment */
end = sbrk(0); /* start != end at this point */

/* Try to allocate in chunks as much as possible. */
while (end == sbrk(0)) {
    malloc(1048576);

    if (end == sbrk(0)){
        maxMemory = maxMemory + 1048576;
    }
}

return maxMemory;
```

So the thing that I don't understand is that :

If you do :

```
start = sbrk(0);
malloc(1);
end = sbrk(0);
```

OK, end !=start

But :

```
start = sbrk(0);
malloc(1048576);
end = sbrk(0);
```

start == end

So, basically, the program break (sbrk(0)) is not moved with larger values. So the given while continues for a very long time until the sbrk(0) is moved and I get a really large Max value of ~68gb.

I would expect that any malloc would initially move the data segment, but it doesn't. Can somebody explain why it does not (where does it allocate it then?) and/or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: sbrk() function is only for use within the malloc family of functions.  so should not be directly called in user functions.

Comment: this line: malloc(1); results in several bytes of the .heap segment, not the .data segment.  It also results in a memory leak as the returned pointer to allocated memory is lost.

Comment: hopefully end is defined as void *  hopefully maxmemory is defined as (32 bit system) int maxmemory = 0 or (64 bit system) long long int maxmemory = 0;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [glibc `malloc` implementation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) allocates using `mmap()` for larger blocks:

> Normally, malloc() allocates memory from the heap, and adjusts the
>   size of the heap as required, using sbrk(2).  When allocating blocks
>   of memory larger than MMAP_THRESHOLD bytes, the glibc malloc()
>   implementation allocates the memory as a private anonymous mapping
>   using mmap(2).  MMAP_THRESHOLD is 128 kB by default, but is adjustable
>   using mallopt(3).  Allocations performed using mmap(2) are unaffected
>   by the RLIMIT_DATA resource limit (see getrlimit(2)).

This threshold can be adjusted using [`mallopt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html) by setting `M_MMAP_THRESHOLD`, but note that newer versions of the library adjust this threshold dynamically by default:

> Note: Nowadays, glibc uses a dynamic mmap threshold by default.  The
>   initial value of the threshold is 128*1024, but when blocks larger
>   than the current threshold and less than or equal to
>   DEFAULT_MMAP_THRESHOLD_MAX are freed, the threshold is adjusted upward
>   to the size of the freed block.  When dynamic mmap thresholding is in
>   effect, the threshold for trimming the heap is also dynamically
>   adjusted to be twice the dynamic mmap threshold.  Dynamic adjustment
>   of the mmap threshold is disabled if any of the M_TRIM_THRESHOLD,
>   M_TOP_PAD, M_MMAP_THRESHOLD, or M_MMAP_MAX parameters is set.